# Disable Access to  Drives for Limited Users in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, user-accounts, group-policy

How can I restrict users from accessing certain drives or partitions for Limited User Account in Windows XP/Vista/7. Kinldy guide me, there was something about Group User policy but guide me in steps please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is all that you want to do, it would be easier to just deny read rights to all limited users on those partitions/drives.

Comment: Well thank you, i also figured that out while working on the Properties>Security Settings of certain partitions.

Comment: Well if it works, please upvote this answer and/or mark it as the answer (click the check mark).

Comment: Well i certainly know to accept the answer, but there is time limit to accept an answer initially, i might be new on Super User, but I have been stack overflow for quite a time.

Comment: Apologies, and welcome to Superuser.

Comment: What's the (best) way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable access to the drive and hide it from My Computer, so that it appears as if the drive doesn't even exist, you can do this with Group Policy settings (in Windows Vista/7 Pro/Business/Enterprise/Ultimate) or using a registry edit (all versions of Windows). Instructions on how to do this are in the related question, [How to hide drive for specific users in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/238235/how-to-hide-drive-for-specific-users-in-windows-7/238393#238393).

Comment: Really a detailed answer and link thank you very helpful

Answer (score 0):

the simple solution to restric drives from any user.
go to specific drive right click and go to security tab, go to edit and add administrator select check name and press ok, then provide full access. remove other user froms lists except administrator. press ok and wait for the process to complete. Thus drive is nu accessible to other users.
if other user try to access he will need administrator access.

Comment: this is process is only for windows 7/ vista Home or home premium