# How would I specify specific start menu items for a certain user?

Tags: windows, start-menu, gpedit

I have a member of my family with a user account that I am restricting,

I have already added loads of restrictions using the mmc.

What I want to know is, is it possible to set up a separate start menu for that user, with only certain programs available?

I know it is technically possible, because they do it at school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned you Windows version, I assume that you use 7 or Vista. The start menu for a certain user is located at `X:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`, while the one for all users is at `X:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`. You can place different shortcuts there, however it won't stop the user from directly starting an unwanted program directly from its installation folder, unless you prevent
 that.

Comment: Thank you, now, i suppose that leaves the question - how do you block access to internal hard drives (I.E don't list them in my computer?

Comment: You can limit access to specific partitions by right-clicking a partition in the Explorer and select Properties/Security. You can change read/write/listing permissions for each user there. I'm sure you could also hide them via a group policy (and also only allow certain programs to be run), but I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @Liam-W If you want to hide a specific drive letter for a user you can do that. You can also completely disable access to the drive letter too. Follow this tutorial here: [link](http://superuser.com/questions/238235/how-to-hide-drive-for-specific-users-in-windows-7) If you cannot figure out how to find the hex values (which I couldn't) follow this post here: [link](http://superuser.com/questions/645857/how-do-i-find-the-hex-values-that-i-need-to-use-for-the-thread-below) It may look complex but I can assure you it is really easy to follow step by step!