# How do I find the hex values that I need to use to hide a drive letter?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, user-profiles, drive-letter, hexadecimal

In this thread [How to hide drive for specific users in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/238235/how-to-hide-drive-for-specific-users-in-windows-7) it talks about how you can hide drive letters for specific users. I am trying to follow Nathan Hinkle's answer but I am stuck. I need to find 3 hex values that I need to use for 3 different users in the registry.

I need to know the hex values that I must use for:

*USER 1: Disabling Drive N, leave every other drive alone*

*USER 2: Disabling Drive M, leave every other drive alone*

*USER 3: Disabling Drive N & M, leave every other drive alone*

I know this is probably very simple but I just don't understand how to get the values. So please can someone respond with the 3 hex values I need? Also if you feel like you need to do a short tutorial (for future reference) on how you got those exact values then please feel free to do so.

Please refer to the thread link above to know how I need the hex values to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know this is probably very simple but I just don't understand …

I feel your pain.  I would offer my opinion that the reason why you don’t understand [nhinkle’s answer to that other question](https://superuser.com/q/238235/150988#238393) is because it doesn’t exactly make any sense.  I found [this explanation at Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938267.aspx), which says, in effect:

> Take this template:
>
> `**** **ZY  XWVU TSRQ  PONM LKJI  HGFE DCBA`
>
> Write ones below the drive letters that you want to hide.  Write zeros below the `*`s and the drive letters that you don’t want to hide.  You should now have 32 `1`s and `0`s.  Convert to hex.

I’ll assume that you are asking about drives `N:` and `M:`, rather than *N* and *M*. 
To hide drive `N:`, you would have

```
    **** **ZY  XWVU TSRQ  PONM LKJI  HGFE DCBA
    0000 0000  0000 0000  0010 0000  0000 0000
```

which gives you 00002000 (i.e., `2000` hex). 
By the same method, `M:` is `1000`, and “User 3” (`N:` and `M:`) is `3000`.

Comment: Wow that really makes it a whole lot easier...... I was truly wondering where all his zeros were coming from and now that you've explained it it makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the answer given here - it has incorrect hex conversion just like another top google result.

What you need to do is go here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-nodrives.html
And if you want to convert that decimal value to hex, use this site https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html and fill in preceding zeroes if you need (like 0001823F because we needed an 8-digit hex).

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell!

```
'{0:x}' -f [int]('MN'.ToCharArray() | % { 1 -shl ($_ - [char]'A') } | measure -Sum).Sum
# note:           ^^ change this to the uppercase letters of all drives you want to hide
```

The above example produces `3000` (for User 3). Using just `M` produces `1000` (for User 2); just `N` produces `2000` (User 1). Here's how it works:

- `.ToCharArray()` splits your drive specifier string into individual characters that will move along the pipeline independently
- `%` is shorthand for `ForEach-Object`; it allows running a chunk of code for each item on the pipeline or, in our case, transforming each item before passing it down the pipeline
- `$_ - [char]'A'` subtracts the `A` character from the current letter character on the pipeline, calculating the bit position for one drive letter (e.g. `C` - `A` = 2)
- `1 -shl (...)` calculates the numeric value that will hide just the one current drive by placing a binary digit 1 in the appropriate bit position
- `measure -Sum` collects and adds up all the numbers coming down the pipeline, combining all the individual-drive-hiding values into one number
- `[int](...).Sum` gets the `Sum` property from the measurement results object and casts it to an integer (as opposed to a double-precision floating point number, which can't easily be formatted as hex)
- `'{0:x}' -f` formats the number on the right-hand side as a hex string