# How do I prevent a user from accessing a network drive?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-registry, network-shares

Is it possible to prevent a user from accessing a network drive through Explorer, mapping the drive, or with the Run command -- for example, by modifying the registry?

I found part of the solution [here](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/161), but I would still like to know how to disable connecting with the Run command. I plan to make a VBScript to modify the registry.

Comment: Why have a network drive / share if you don't want people to access it?

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/q/645857/150988) and the things it links to might help you.

Comment: This can be handled by modifying the permissions on the folder itself.