# Disable harddrives to limit what space the OS can access as a security measure

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, security

I have a laptop with 2 internal harddrives. One of them with an operating system (OS). This setup is what I use mostly.

I have an external harddrive also with Windows 7/8 that I boot from sometimes. When I am booting from the external harddrive I want the two internal drives to not be accessible. Is there some setting in windows or startup script I can run to do this?

This is due to security issues. I want to use the same hardware, but have a well defined memory access.

Comment: Generally, anything that can be done with software (“some setting in Windows or startup script I can run”) can be undone with software. If you want to be secure, you should probably be looking at hardware solutions (e.g., open the case and unplug the drives). But, if you’re willing to settle for Security Through Obscurity, you might want to look at [How to hide drive for specific users in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/238235/150988) and [How do I find the hex values that I need to use?](http://superuser.com/q/645857/150988)