# Restrict access to hdd or partition in windows 8 to admin only

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, permissions

I have extra internal and external hard drives in my computer.

One I use to keep some unused files, and the other I use for backup of my C: drive.

How can I limit anyone that uses my pc under the guest account to even be able to see this HDD?

Furthermore, I actually would like to give guest access to a media folder in one of the hard drives, so I would like to know:

1. Can I hide a drive from a guest user? How?
2. Can I only make folders unavailable (not hide them) and still share a folder? How?

Comment: Possible answer here?: http://superuser.com/questions/238235/how-to-hide-drive-for-specific-users-in-windows-7

Comment: I've edited the question, its for windows 8, not 7. But I'll definitely check that link out. Thanks.

Comment: No probs, it may work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually pretty simple.

**1** - Right-click the drive of choice in Computer

**2** - Properties

**3** - Security

**4** - Update access as needed. (In this case, removed "Users")

Taken from "**[grawity's](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity)**" post on this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/238235/how-to-hide-drive-for-specific-users-in-windows-7) that wasn't chosen as the correct answer, but it definitely is in this situation.

Thanks to [yassarikhan786](https://superuser.com/users/250742/yassarikhan786) for pointing out a similar question.