# Restrict user access to only the system drive on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, users

I have a created a new user (standard account type) on my Windows 10 Pro machine and I need to limit the access of this user to C:/ (the system drive) only.
Any other existing partitions, or hard drives on the computer (including any usb  storage sticks) must not be accessible to this user. And if I later add a new HDD to the computer under letter say X:, this user should not be able to access that as well.

Basically anything not on C:/ should not be accessible to this user.

How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: [Edit] your question to indicate if you are using Professional or Home.

Comment: Edited. It's Pro.

Comment: You should be able to use [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/hide-physical-drives-in-windows-explorer-25e8ddaf-b6d4-e5ac-5342-ff22eaefb2f1).  In order to hire multiple drives add up their value. Duplicate [here](https://superuser.com/questions/238235/how-to-hide-drive-for-specific-users-in-windows-7)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide drive for specific users in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/238235/how-to-hide-drive-for-specific-users-in-windows-7)